# Can I attack with a weapon and also use a net if I do it in that order?

Tags: dnd-5e

If you have two attacks for any reason, using a net clearly prevents you from using any more. Suppose you have a trident and you attack with your trident first, though: can you swap to your net for your second attack (assuming swapping weapons like that is allowed as the free object interaction) and get both off anyway?

Yes, I know nets are not very good.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [How many attacks does using a net let you have?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48737/how-many-attacks-does-using-a-net-let-you-have)?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Not really. That was asking whether you could make your other attacks with different weapons, whereas this takes the "no" from the other question for granted and asks if you can circumvent the restriction by changing the order. (Note: answers to the other question might also answer this question, but by my understanding that doesn't automatically make it a duplicate if the questions are different.)

Comment: @Miniman that is my understanding as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the PHB, page 148:

> When you use an action, bonus action, or reaction to attack with a net, you can make only one attack regardless of the number of attacks you can normally make.

This is a deterministic statement. Whatever action you use to attack with a net can only be used to make a single attack (the attack with the net). Order doesn't matter here. Attacking with the trident bars you from attacking with the net with one of your other attacks.

If the rule for nets said something along the lines of "Attacking with a net prevents you from making any further attacks with the same action.", then you could attack with another weapon, then attack with the net. As phrased, this isn't allowed.

Comment: why would the dual wielder let you make attacks when you cited "you can make only one attack regardless of the number of attacks you can normally make"?

Comment: @Mouhgouda Because the text for the net ties the limit only to the action used for the net.