# Can you make multiple attacks with a net or a weapon with the loading property if you have multiple individual actions or reactions?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, actions, reactions

The [net](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/net) item has a special property which says:

> When you use an action, bonus action, or reaction to attack with a net, you can make only one attack regardless of the number of attacks you can normally make.

Similarly, the [Loading property](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#WeaponProperties) says:

> ...you can fire only one piece of ammunition from it when you use an action, bonus action, or reaction to fire it, regardless of the number of attacks you can normally make.

**If I gain additional actions or reactions with which to attack with these weapons, can I make multiple attacks in one round?**

---

For example, extra actions from sources like Action Surge:

> ...you can push yourself beyond your normal limits for a moment. On your turn, you can take one additional action.

...bonus action attacks from sources like War Priest:

> ...When you use the Attack action, you can make one weapon attack as a bonus action.

...reaction attacks from sources like Inspiring Surge:

> ...when you use your Action Surge feature, you can choose one creature within 60 feet of you that is allied with you. That creature can make one melee or ranged weapon attack with its reaction, provided that it can see or hear you.

Comment: related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48737/how-many-attacks-does-using-a-net-let-you-have (and this question may cause the linked question to be a duplicate....

Comment: It's also possible that this is two questions.

Comment: @goodguy5 I think that related question is more asking if you can net and then use another weapon, whereas I am asking about multiple nets or multiple loaded weapon attacks. Which two questions, one for net and one for Loading?

Comment: "A weapon attack" and "Attack action" are two different things. Please read this answer and edit your question accordingly https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105781/

Comment: Yes, those would be the two questions. but I'm not sure because the verbiage is so close.

Comment: @enkryptor I don't believe that influences my question. When you take an action (such as the Attack action) to make an attack, you only get one with the net or loading weapon (even if a feature like Extra Attack would allow two). They are both involved but separate.

Comment: @V2Blast it is the level 10 feature of the Purple Dragon Knight (or Banneret) in Swords Coast Adventurer's Guide

Comment: @DavidCoffron: Ah, I see it now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Mutiple actions give you multiple attacks with a loading weapon (or net)

Since the wording for the net special property and the loading property are essentially and mechanically identical, I'll only focus on loading (but it will apply equally to both).

> you can fire only one piece of ammunition from it when you use an action, bonus action, or reaction to fire it, regardless of the number of attacks you can normally make.

The rule is simple: any time you take an action, bonus action, or reaction you get only one attack with the weapon. You take one action, you get one attack. This applies to each and every action, bonus action, and reaction you do.

Nothing in this rule restricts anything about a future action, bonus action, or reaction that you might take. In other words, every action is limited to only one attack from the loading weapon (or net), but additional actions (etc.) have no additional restrictions.

If the rule was intended to limit loading weapons or nets to once a round or once a turn, it would simply say so.