# What actions can prevent you from taking another action because of the restrictions that are placed on the second action?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions

Or in other words: What rules prevent you from doing something you would otherwise be able to do?

I am worried about this question being too broad, but I feel like there can't be very many examples like the following:

1. Under the rules on bonus action spells, it states:

   > A spell cast with a bonus action is especially swift. You must use a bonus action on your turn to cast the spell, provided that you haven’t already taken a bonus action this turn. You can’t cast another spell during the same turn, except for a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action.

   First, this means that if you cast a bonus action spell, the restrictions on them prevent you from casting non-cantrip spells. **However** if instead you cast a non-cantrip spell the restrictions on bonus action spells prevent you from casting any bonus action spells. You are normally allowed to cast a bonus action spell, but here, their own rules prevent that. That this is how bonus action spells work is shown [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47421)
2. Under the net weapon, the "special" property states:

   > When you use an action, bonus action, or reaction to attack with a net, you can make only one attack regardless of the number of attacks you can normally make.

   First, if you have Extra Attack, and your first attack is with a net, the restrictions on nets prevent you from making more attacks, [as shown in this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48737). **However**, [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/150891), along with the previous one, possibly show that if you instead make your first attack with, say, a dagger, the restrictions on nets prevent you from attacking with a net. You are normally allowed to attack with a net, but here, its own rules prevent that.

Are there other examples of times similar to these?

Comment: Is there a reason you are looking for these examples? What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: Also, sidenote, it is often not the best idea to base the premise of a question partly on an Q&A that is only a couple hours old at most. Usually best to see what answers come in and how the community votes and let things settle before claiming something is decided.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose These are just some, to me, incredibly unintuitive moments in the game that warrant being individually explained to my players, and I'm wondering whether there are others I should look out for or be aware of.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose I can remove and hold onto this question for a few days if that would be more suitable

Comment: It is really up to you (and I guess how the community feels about it) I don't think it will mess too much with this question since you have another example there already, it was more of a general note. But it can often mess questions up when a better opposite answer comes in and removes the premise of the question. So, just watch out for that.

Comment: I think this either too broad or unclear (most likely too broad.) There are *lots* of situations where something has happened that now prevents you from doing something else.

Comment: This is pretty broad, as it includes "you took a certain action, so you now can't take a different action this turn", "you attacked one target so you aren't attacking other targets", etc. What's your use case?

Comment: As currently phrased too broad, but I think there is a stringent question in there, somewhere.

Comment: @NautArch I'm not really sure how to *describe* what I want. But a clear thing I wouldn't want is the fact that becoming unconscious prevents you from taking actions. Or that moving to a location where a spell has no eligible targets would make you unable to target anything. These things feel... *simpler* to me, they involve effectively only one character and are not horribly contrived scenarios. They come about from the rules themselves not from effects of spells or the like.

Comment: Sure, but those technically qualify for your question. I get the frustration, but things you find 'contrived' others may not. And vice versa.

Comment: Ok, You are asking for rules prohibitives, where a given rule overrides your ability to do something, as opposed to natural prohibitives, where the general environment prohibits something. I suggest changing the question to: "What rules prevent you from doing something you otherwise would be able to do?" But be warned, even that seems too broad.

Comment: @MarkWells has this made the question more specified? At least your two examples, taking an action and attacking a target, no longer apply.

Comment: Kind of, but it's still very unclear what your intended use is, which makes it hard to provide a useful answer.