# is it possible to use a net and shove in the same turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, actions

My PC has multiple attacks. I would like to know if it is possible to hit with a net (first attack) and then shove the opponent (second attack). Apparently using a net prevents to make a second attack; on the other hand, shove is not properly an attack. Thanks for the replies :)

Net:

> When you use an action, Bonus Action, or Reaction to Attack with a
> net, you can make only one Attack regardless of the number of attacks
> you can normally make.

Shove:

> Using the Attack action, you can make a Special melee Attack to shove
> a creature, either to knock it prone or push it away from you. If
> you’re able to make multiple attacks with the Attack action, this
> Attack replaces one of them.

Comment: We can answer with out this info, but can you give your level and class?

Comment: Also, does [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48737/how-many-attacks-does-using-a-net-let-you-have) answer your question about how many attacks using a net lets you have? I'm going to close as a duplicate for now, but please let us if know if it is different and how.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.